# Creating an installer with Visual Studio - How do I control the file structure?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, outlook-addin

Quick question here, I'm using Visual Studio to create an Outlook add-in. I've created the code and it boots up nicely in Outlook. Now to actually creating an installer.. This is what I've done so far, created a new installer project and added the files (dll and vsto) from the debug folder of the actual outlook project. But when I build it and run the installer, the default path selected is `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Default Company Name\My Project\`

Seems like `[AppDataFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`are variables. But how can I control them? I want the installer to install the files necessary in the correct locations. But I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this path to the one that you want, or you can just change the variables by right click on your setup project and hit properties, you'll have these properties there an some other ones that you might want to change.

Also for deployment you should add the files from Release and not Debug.

**Edit**

You can use program file folder through: *[ProgramFilesFolder]* variable.

If you add the files as 'Add Project Output', visual studio will add all the files from that project output, and it will automatically detect all required dependencies like .Net Framework, etc. If your application uses other external files as ini, txt, etc files that are not part of the project output you need to add them manually.

Comment: Yes but 'AppDataFolder][Manufacturer]\\[ProductName]' is what it says by default. I don't know the names of the variables it uses. I want to install the Addin to 'C:\Program Files\My Folder' but in order to do that I need to know the variable of 'C:\Program Files' which is '%programfiles%' in environment variables, but this doesn't work here. I don't want to specify 'C:\' since a user might have Windows installed on 'D:\' for example. Also, does the installer pack all the files necessary from the source path? In my case, the Release folder?

Comment: This is beautiful thank you!:) This really should be better documented, shame on you Microsoft *points finger

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default location to whatever you want by modifying Application Folder properties
[image: Application Folder Properties screen shot]